# Forge Viewer getState() returns unexpected values of isolated items

Tags: javascript, angular, autodesk-viewer

We are using the latest forge viewer in our angular application and we are saving the current state of the viewer in our DB so that we can later restore the state again.

Due to intensive testing we found, that the isolated nodes are not correctly saved internally.We are receiving the current state via `viewer.getState()` and the contained `objectSet` should have all the selected, hidden and isolated values.

We could reproduce our problem if we load a model and then select and deselect a few times a component, so that in the end everything is shown as in the beginning, then we would expect and empty isolated array, though the array contains multiple values, even though in the viewer is nothing shown as isolated.

Is this due to problem in the viewer or in the model?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, sounds like an interesting test case.  Could you tell me if the source model was Revit, Navisworks, Autocad, Civil3D, IFC, Inventor, Fusion or something else ?

That could give me a clue, as to something with the Assembly Tree causing an issue.

Comment: Hey Michael, it was an IFC File which we used back then but I'm not sure where it was created from.

Comment: ah.. good to know.  Our IFC support has gone through a lot of changes in the last 12 months, so it might be worth uploading, converting the IFC file again and double checking.  In any case, I'll bring it up with engineering for additional QA -  thanks ! ref LMV-7239